# Rails 3.x MySQL Monitor/Reviewer

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

back in 2007 and 2008 I loved to monitor my Rails app with query-reviewer, but nowadays with Rails 3.x it's really hard to find a good MySQL monitior/reviewer plugin. Any suggestions?

Greetz,
Mario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/nesquena/query_reviewer works with Rails 3!

:)

Answer (score 0):

How about http://www.newrelic.com/RPMlite-rails.html  ?